# In-app purchase not logging on firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, firebase-analytics

After adding Firebase Analytics to my Android app, in-app purchases are not automatically logging in Firebase.
But in log it is showing as event recorded..

> V/FA-SVC  (14957): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.xyz.abc',
>   name='in_app_purchase(_iap)', params=Bundle[{quantity=1,
>   firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,  price=270000000, value=270000000,
>   currency=INR, product_name=, product_id=com.com.xyz.abc.500coins}]}

and in my firebase project settings i even linked Google play account & added SHA-1 fingerprint also. But still i couldn't see any in-app purchase logs under firebase conversion section.

Comment: We are having the same issue in Android only. Works fine in iOS. Any update?